# InputStreamReader vs FileReader

Tags: java, stream

I can't seem to determine any difference between `InputStreamReader` and `FileReader` besides the way the two are initialized. Is there any benefit to using one or the other? Most other articles cover `FileInputStream` vs `InputStreamReader`, but I am contrasting with `FileReader` instead. Seems to me they both have the same purpose.

Comment: Look at this questions, it has answers from (any ONLY from) my favorite 3 SO users! (Jon Skeet is more than favorite)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First, `InputStreamReader` can handle all input streams, not just files. Other examples are network connections, classpath resources and ZIP files.

Second, `FileReader` until Java 11 did not allow you to specify an encoding and instead only used the plaform default encoding, which made it pretty much useless as using it would result in corrupted data when the code is run on systems with different platform default encodings.

Since Java 11, `FileReader` is a useful shortcut for wrapping an `InputStreamReader` around a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: That is what I figured by first glance (from a cross-platform standpoint), but I was wondering why they even implemented `FileReader`.

Comment: @Spliff: From that point of view, everything in the API that implicitly uses the default encoding was a bad idea; I guess at the time the API was desigend this didn't seem to be such a problem. What I really can't understand is why they still haven't added a FileReader constructor that takes an encoding.

Comment: To read 7500000 lines of string from file,    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)); // take 20 minute
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); // take 3 min,  So in my case FileReader is much faster then InputStream Reader

Comment: @DwivediJi: Whatever is causing that performance difference, it has nothing to do with FileReader or InputStreamReader, because FileReader is nothing but a subclass of InputStreamReader that adds some constructors which wraps the parameters in a FileInputStream.

Comment: In Java 11 new constructor have been added to FileReader which allows you to specify Charset `public FileReader(File file, Charset charset) throws IOException`

Answer (score 9):

FileReader reads character from a file in the file system. InputStreamReader reads characters from any kind of input stream. The stream could be a FileInputStream, but could also be a stream obtained from a socket, an HTTP connection, a database blob, whatever.

I usually prefer using an InputStreamReader wrapping a FileInputStream to read from a file because it allows specifying a specific character encoding.

Answer (score 3):

FileReader extends InputStreamReader.  The only differences is that FileReader has constructors which assume you are reading from a file such as `String filename`, `File file` and `FileDescriptor fd`

I suggest you have a look at the source for FileReader to know more.

Comment: So a FileReader is made specifically for streaming files only (no other type of stream is possible), whereas InputStreamReader does the same but accepts other types of streams as well?

Comment: @Spliff: the API docs spell it out: "Convenience class for reading character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream. "

Comment: It's the "bridge" terminology that is throwing me off with the API docs, as if one is so closely tied to the other that they both are required together; as if I couldn't do it with an `InputStreamReader` alone.