# Reading from file. Which is a better approach and why?

Tags: java, java-io

```
BufferedReader buf2=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D:/info.txt")));
```

Out of these two methods for reading the contents of a file which method is better and why?

```
BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/info.txt"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [InputStreamReader vs FileReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991770/inputstreamreader-vs-filereader)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both lines are equivalent; in both cases you'll get a `BufferedReader` which will allow you to read text from the file.

A possible advantage of the first approach is that you can change it slightly to specify the character encoding that you want to use for reading the file, for example:

```
BufferedReader buf2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("D:/info.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

`FileReader` does not allow you to specify the character encoding and will always use the default character encoding of your platform, which is not always what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From java docs:

> FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters. For reading streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileInputStream.

So, it depends on your requirements.

For more clarity keep reading:

> FileReader can't handle network connections streams, etc.
>
> FileReader doesn't care of encoding but uses the plaform default encoding, and hence limits platform independence.

Thus, forget `FileReader` (most of the times).

Answer (score 1):

Readers are for text I/O, while Streams are for binary I/O . You have to take care of Encoding/Decoding issue while using Reader which could be avoided with InputStream.

Take a look at [FileInputStream vs FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155226/fileinputstream-vs-filereader) for  details.

Answer (score 1):

If used as is, both have exactly the same effect. However, using `InputStreamReader` allows you to specify the text encoding as second parameter to the constructor, and you should nearly always do that because [There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text.html).